# How to only include some files on a Eclipse project?

Tags: eclipse

I would like to create an Eclipse project from an existing project made with IAR Workbench.

I have a list of files I want to build, but I don't know how I can tell Eclipse to only include some files only.

I've discovered that I can "exclude" a file by clicking on the file then choosing `Resource Configuration/Exclude`. I've also found that I can place some filters on `Resource Filters`, but I have found where I can just include some paths such as

```
${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/Foo/Bar/foo.c
```

How is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question: **you can't**.

What you can do is to list the files on your Git repository and the files that should be excluded from your Eclipse project. Then you make the difference between both list to get the list of file that are on Eclipse.

Then from the `.cproject` file you can edit the key

```
<storageModule>
<!-- ... -->
<configuration>
    <!-- ... -->
    <sourceEntries>
       <entry excluding="{{file}}|{{file}}..."
    </sourceEntries>
</configuration>
</storageModule>
```